# Select by index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Have a dataframe in Pandas like this (id-index):

```
             pa         wat
id          
1000         12         1
1001         301        1
1002          0         0
```

How can I get the values from 1001 index id.
I've tried .loc-but doesnt work.

Comment: Can you show how that doesn't work? (What did you try and what was the unexpected result)

Comment: `.loc` is what you need to use to [select by label](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label) (index), perhaps you're using the wrong datatype (e.g. 1000 is a string instead of an integer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ix` or `loc` if need output as `Series`:

```
print (df.ix[1001])
pa     301
wat      1
Name: 1001, dtype: int64

print (df.loc[1001])
pa     301
wat      1
Name: 1001, dtype: int64
```

And if need output `Dataframe` use double `[]`:

```
print (df.ix[[1001]])
       pa  wat
id            
1001  301    1
```

If `type` of index is `string` use:

```
print (type(df.index[0]))
<class 'str'>

print (df.loc['1001'])
pa     301
wat      1
Name: 1001, dtype: int64
```

If need select all rows to the end, add `:` (thank you [sirfz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423665/select-by-index-in-pandas/38423693#comment64254000_38423693)):

```
print (df.ix[1001:])
       pa  wat
id            
1001  301    1
1002    0    0
```

Comment: And to select values from `1001`: `df.loc[1001:]` (or `df.loc['1001':]` if the index values are strings)